# AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'get_updates'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a VAE with TensorFlow Keras backend and I'm using Adam as the optimizer. the code I used is attached below.

```
    def compile(self, learning_rate=0.0001):
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                       loss=self._calculate_combined_loss,
                       metrics=[_calculate_reconstruction_loss,
                                calculate_kl_loss(self)])
```

The TensorFlow version I'm using is 2.11.0. The error I'm getting is

```
AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'get_updates'
```

I'm suspecting the issues arise because of the version mismatch. Can someone please help me to sort out the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: calculate_kl_loss(self) what is that

Comment: Use a legacy Adam since the current implementation doesn't have `get_updates()` method any more: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/legacy/Adam

Answer (score 8):

Try replacing your 2nd line
"optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)"
by
"optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.**legacy**.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)"

For further information, check tf 2.11.0 Release 11/28/2022 in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases
It indicates in particular that:
"The tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer base class now points to the new Keras optimizer, while the old optimizers have been moved to the tf.keras.optimizers.legacy namespace."

Answer (score 2):

Of late, I had to use the tensorflow2.5 and I replaced all "import keras" by "import tensorflow.keras".
Now I use tensorflow2.12 and I met this error and when I returned those replacements; this error was removed.
thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Two ways worked for me,

1. By using  `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD` - instead of  `tf.keras.optimizers.SGD`
2. Importing statement is changed from
   `import tensorflow.keras as keras` to 'import keras'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `tensorflow.keras.optimizers`  with `tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
```

The above worked for me.